# Vuepress Internationalization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

I am currently working with Vuepress. But I want multiple languages in my Vuepress site. After 3 days of struggling I have decided to put my question here. (Yes I checked the Vuepress documentation: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/i18n.html#default-theme-i18n-config)

The Problem: In my config I have Dutch as main language. When I want to put English as locale. My navigation wont update. Here is my config:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'Portfolio Bjorn',
    description: ' ',
    themeConfig: {
        nav: [
            { text: 'Over mij', link: '/overmij.html'},
            { text: 'Portolfio', link: '/portfolio/'},
            { text: 'Contact', link: '/contact.html'},
            {
                text: 'Languages',
                items: [
                  { text: 'Dutch', link: '/' },
                  { text: 'English', link: '/english/' }
                ]
            } 
        ],
        sidebar: {
            '/portfolio/': [
                '',
                'school',
                'zelfgemaakt'

            ]
        },
        locales: {

            '/english': {
            lang: 'en-Us',
            nav: [
            { text: 'About', link: '/about.html'},
            { text: 'Portfolio', link: '/portfolio_en/'},
            { text: 'Contact', link: '/contact_en.html'},
            ]   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I also have a picture of my folder structure:

[image: I also have a picture of my folder structure:]

I hope someone knows the answer to this so I can continue.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a default theme.

You made a simple mistake in your config – you placed your general `locale` options in your `themeConfig`.

Instead, you need to define your locale for the site in general, and then you can also define localized data specific to your theme config.

Your config should look like so:

```
module.exports = {

  locales: {
    /* This is where you place your general locale config */
    '/': {
      lang: 'nl-NL',
    },
    '/en/': {
      lang: 'en-US',
      title: 'english title of the website'
    }
  },


  themeConfig: {
    locales: {
      /* This is where you place your theme specific, localized data */
      '/': {
        nav: [/* dutch nav */]
      },
      '/en/': {
        nav: [/* english nav */]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set your base locale, and set the defaults there, rather than the standard way you are doing above, for example:

```
module.exports = {
    title: 'Portfolio Bjorn',
    description: ' ',
    themeConfig: {
        locales: {
            '/': {
                label: 'Dutch',
                nav: [
                    { text: 'Over mij', link: '/overmij.html'},
                    { text: 'Portolfio', link: '/portfolio/'},
                    { text: 'Contact', link: '/contact.html'},
                ]
            },
            '/english': {
                label: 'English',
                nav: [
                    { text: 'About', link: '/about.html'},
                    { text: 'Portfolio', link: '/portfolio_en/'},
                    { text: 'Contact', link: '/contact_en.html'},
                ]   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also don't need to define the language dropdown in the nav, I believe it's automatically triggered when you set multiple languages

Comment: the code above didn't work. I even tried to put my english folder in the public folder. But no results...